# how to resize div when browser resize using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to resize the entire 'div' container using javascript ? Inside my div i have 2 images and placed one over another. 1st image has is 720x1280 and 2nd image has 40x40. Now, while resizing my div container both the images should get resized proposinally.

```
function addWidth() {
var elem = document.getElementById("Image1");
if (elem != null) {
var mydiv = elem.clientWidth;
document.getElementById("divImage").style.width = mydiv + "px";
}
}
function resizediv() {
var height = window.innerWidth;
if (document.body.clientHeight) {
height = document.body.clientHeight;
}
height = parseInt(height) - 10;
document.getElementById("Image1").style.height = parseInt(height - document.getElementById("divImage").offsetTop - 8) + "px";
}
window.onresize = resizediv;
```

I have tried for an single image and its works fine. But i want the same to happens for an div container.

Comment: Could you not just add `max-width: 100%` to the images in CSS?

Comment: I think this can be solved in css...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    addWidth();
    resizediv();
});
```

Along with this, like @Alex said, you can also add `width:100%` for the images.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is it possible to resize the entire 'div' container using javascript ? Inside my div i have 2 images and placed one over another. 1st image has 720x1280 and 2nd image has 40x40. Now, while resizing my div container both the images should get resized proposinally.

Comment: i dont have any idea to do. I just tried "fit to screen" with an single image. it works fine. Attached above.